# Have Jewish scholars evaluated the "Odes of Solomon" as being Jewish or Christian in origin?

Tags: provenance

I have just learned of the existence of an ancient Syrian text called "The Odes of Solomon". This seems to "round out" the collection of Solomonic literature such as the Proverbs, Qeholeth, Song of Solomon and Wisdom of Solomon.

Have Jewish scholars seen this as suggesting any particular readings that indicate that they were written by someone aware of the 1st century controversy regarding Jesus and if so, does it "take a side"?

Also, how is an "ode" different from a "song", if at all?

Comment: Which 1st century controversy regarding Jesus? Must answers come only from Jewish scholars? My knowledge is limited to only reading a few of the odes and the Wikipedia page, but I don't see how the text could be Jewish

Comment: Hmm... I'm seeking the Jewish perspective, preferably something definitive but any qualified analysis will be helpful and I won't down vote any answer that provides some insight into the nature of this document. The free part of the article actually suggests different possible origins/slants/biases including Jewish (not to impugn the document's author as being humanly motivated).

Comment: Are you asking about the text as it exists or the text as scholars believe may have once existed? The former is, in my unlearned opinion, unambiguously Christian

Comment: Consider this a peek under a rock I was not aware of before. I was hoping to get the "skinny" on it and my first order of business was to find out in what context it arose. But really, any foundational information that will be of use in doing my own analysis (should it prove to be of interest to me after learning about it) would be welcomed. I'm normally not a big down voter so consider this a broad net. Thanks b a.

Answer (score 4):

References to the Trinity (Father, Son, Holy Spirit) as well as the Virgin Birth described in Ode 19 make it obvious to one who reads ["The Odes of Solomon"](http://gnosis.org/library/odes.htm) that they are of Christian authorship.

Comment: Ode 23.22 also refers to Father, Son, and Holy Spirit. Ode 33 also smacks of Christian authorship.